# Unable To Add User To AD Via C# Graph API -- Why Is This "OData Error" Occurring When Calling GraphServiceClient.Users.PostAsync()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When attempting to Add/Invite a User to Azure AD Default Directory via Microsoft Graph in C#, as per [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

```
var requestBody = new User
{
  AccountEnabled = true,
  DisplayName = "StackOverflow TestUser",
  MailNickname = "Stackie",
  Mail = "test@tempmailin.com",
  PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
  {
    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
    Password = "testpwabcd",
  }
};
var result = await graphServiceClient.Users.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

The following Exception is caught upon attempting the Post:

```
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: 'Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
```

"[External Code]" is formatted just like that, and does not provide any further information (Probably referring to the C# Code calling the API.). I've been unable to find any way to pass in OData to Users.PostAsync(). The Graph Client is connected via a Client Secret:

```
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
```

I've verifed that the Graph Client is properly connected, as it is able to properly Get a User:

```
User user1 = await graphServiceClient.Users["TestGUID-12345678910"].GetAsync();
```

And also able to successfully add an existing user in AD to a Group:

```
var requestBody2 = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.ReferenceCreate
{
  OdataId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/12345TestUserID",
};
await graphServiceClient.Groups["GroupID"].Members.Ref.PostAsync(requestBody2);
```

Trying `var result = await graphServiceClient.Invitations.PostAsync(requestBody);` fails with the same Error. Alternatively, `var differentTry = graphServiceClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(requestBody);` does pass through, with the following Object Parameters returned:[image: Var Parameters For Users.ToPostRequest() Call]
However, the user is not added to AD.

I've tried the .Request.AddAsync(User) method (`await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);`) in other helpful Articles, like [this one](https://damienbod.com/2022/03/11/create-azure-b2c-users-with-microsoft-graph-and-asp-net-core/) by DamienBod, but I think that it is deprecated, as the Compiler throws Errors upon using it.

The API Permissions of the Tenant whose Settings are Configured for the Graph Client are as follows:
[image: API Permissions For Microsoft Graph Tenant &+ App.]

Has anyone experienced this Error before and found a way around it, or alternatively does anyone know another way to add a User to Azure AD Default Directory via Microsoft Graph in C#? Thanks so much!

**Edit:** As per Tiny Wang's Answer Below, adding the "UserPrincipalName" to the requestBody with an E-Mail Address using the #EXT# + Domain Extension fixed the problem!

Comment: `await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);` is used for `Microsoft.Graph` version before 5.0.0 and for v5 version we need to use  `graphServiceClient.Users.PostAsync`

Comment: for inviting external users, we need to use [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue like below

[image]

and

[image]

and my code like this worked well,

[image]

I think the issue is related to `userPrincipalName` which had a [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-body) here

> this should map to the user's email name. The general format is
> alias@domain, where domain must be present in the tenant's collection
> of verified domains.

Code I used:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            
var requestBody = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "StackOverflow TestUser",
    MailNickname = "Stackie",
    //UserPrincipalName = "test@tempmailin.com",
    UserPrincipalName = "test@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
        Password = "8uhb*UHB",
    }
};
var result = await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much!! By changing the @ Symbol to an Underscore and adding #EXT#@domain.com (E.G. test@tempmailin.com --> test_tempmailin.com#EXT#@testtenantname.onmicrosoft.com), the request went through successfully with your help. You're the best!

Comment: This API is a joke to use. I'm running into this "error message" (if you can call it that) on a different request (list mailboxes).

Comment: For real, it would help a great deal if the API's Error Messages would show something beyond just "OData Error." Were you able to get past that Issue with the List Mailboxes?

Comment: also struggling with password reset. But, wrt "error messages"...
if you drill into the OData exception , there is an "Error" property which does give more useful info

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to add a custom email as the username, you can do it as follows

```
var requestBody = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "John Doe",
    UserPrincipalName = johndoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d",
    },
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
    {
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            Issuer = contoso.onmicrosoft.com,
            IssuerAssignedId = jhon@gmail.com,
            SignInType = "emailAddress"
        }
     }
};

var result = await _graphClient.Users.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Remember to replace `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` with your tenant name.

In this way, the user will have jhon@gmail.com (or the custom email you provided) as the username.